# How Do Sine and Cosine Mathematically Describe a Circle (Proof)?

Tags: trigonometry, circles

In trigonometry and related fields, it's common knowledge that the sine and cosine functions are intimately connected with the unit circle. It's often taken for granted that these functions describe the x and y coordinates on the circle as it's parametrized by an angle θ. The equations are typically given as:

$$ x(\theta) = \cos(\theta) $$
$$ y(\theta) = \sin(\theta) $$

where $( \theta )$ is the angle from the positive x-axis to the radius of the circle in a counter-clockwise direction.

I'm looking for a formal mathematical proof or explanation that clearly shows how these functions relate to the geometric circle. Specifically, I'm interested in understanding the foundational principles that establish sine and cosine as the x and y coordinates of a circle when the angle θ is varied.

Can anyone provide an explanation or point me toward resources that prove or visually demonstrate this relationship beyond just the unit circle definition?

Comment: Can't prove a definition.  What in your mind is the *meaning* of $\sin$ and $\cos$?  Other than that they represent the coordinates of a circle, what *else* do they mean?  If I don't assume they are the coordinates of a circle then I don't know *anything* about the functions and I can't prove anything about them any more than you can prove anything about the function $ishkabibble$.  (Let $ishkabibble: \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$.  Prove $ishkabibble(x) = \frac {\ln{|x +17|}}{|x|+\pi}$.

Comment: That's the definition of sine and cosine. Note that they were defined thousands of years before we invented algebra or our current numeral system. They are fundamentally geometric notions related to the properties of circles.

Comment: Draw the unit circle.  Look at the right triangle with one vertex at the origin and the other at $(x(\theta), y(\theta))$ and legs parallel to the coordinate axis.  Thus the legs have length $x(\theta), y(\theta)$ and the hypotenuse has length $1$ as it is a radius for the unit circle.  Now use that triangle to read off $\sin (\theta)$, etc.

Comment: If your def. of $\sin \theta, \cos \theta$ is: Rt trngle with base angle $\theta$ and $\sin =\frac {opp}{hyp};\cos =\frac{adj}{hyp}$ then we note: Draw a unit circle.  Pick a pt on the circle corresponding to angle $\theta$. then if we drop a perp. down to the $x$ axis, then the perp. from the $x$ axis to the point, the truncated $x$ axis from origin to the perp, and radius from the origin to the point, will form a rt triangle w. hyp$=1$. So $x$ value of the pt is the length of the adj side of the triangle=$\frac{adj}{1}=\cos\theta$ and the $y$ value is length of perp=$\frac{opp}1=\sin\theta$

Answer (score 1):

The problem reduces to proving that $~\sin^2(\theta) + \cos^2(\theta) = 1,~$ since :

- In $~\Bbb{R^2},~$ the unit circle equals
  $~\{(x,y) \;: \;x^2 + y^2 = 1\}.$
- For a circle of radius $~r,~$ any point $~(x,y)~$ on the circle will satisfy $~x = r\cos(\theta), \;y = r\sin(\theta).$

The method of proving this depends on whether the context is [trigonometry:plane geometry] or real analysis.

---

$\underline{\text{In Trigonometry - Plane Geometry}}$

By the pythagorean theorem, the three sides of a right triangle satisfy $~x^2 + y^2 = c^2,~$ where $~x,y~$ are the horizontal and vertical legs, respectively, and $~c~$ is the hypotenuse.

Then, the issue is resolved by the definition of sine and cosine as *opposite over hypotenuse* and *adjacent over hypotenuse* respectively.

---

$\underline{\text{In Real Analysis}}$

Here I will excerpt the approach in "Calculus" 2nd Ed, Vol 1, 1966, by Tom Apostol.

Apostol defines the sine and cosine functions via the following axioms (if such functions might exist):

- A1 : The sine and cosine functions are defined for all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}.$
- A2: $\cos (0) = \sin(\pi/2) = 1, \cos(\pi) = -1.$
- A3: $\cos(y - x) = \cos y \cos x + \sin y \sin x.$
- A4: For $0 < x < \pi/2, ~0 < \cos x < \frac{\sin x}{x} < \frac{1}{\cos x}.$

Paraphrasing Apostol, he then makes the following point:

Examination of the traditional sine and cosine functions against the backdrop of the unit circle (centered at the origin) demonstrates that functions that satisfy the axioms do exist, as long as the domain of the functions is construed to be the *dimensionless* length of the corresponding arc (rather than an angle).

Then, based solely on the axioms, Apostol proves that
$~\sin^2(\theta) + \cos^2(\theta) = 1,~$ as follows:

Invoke A2 and A3, setting $~y = x = \theta.~$

This implies that

$$1 = \cos(0) = \cos(\theta - \theta) = \cos^2(\theta) + \sin^2(\theta).$$

Comment: You may also define $\exp z=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}$ and then define cosine and sine as resp. the even and odd part of $\exp(iz)$. And then of course prove $\cos^2z+\sin^2z=1$. Or you may define first the arctangent by an integral. There are many ways.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Agreed, but I didn't want to make a fool of myself.  Apostol himself makes the point that you can (instead) define the sine and cosine functions by their Taylor series.  However, I intentionally avoided any such alternatives, because I am not confident enough that what I write about such alternatives will be valid.

Comment: If you are taking this approach that the issue is $\sin^2 + \cos^2 = 1$ and then using different definitions to define $\sin, \cos$ by 1) the right triangle definition, or by 2) the Apostle axioms, you should consider the simplest and very widely accepted definition by 0) the unit circle definition-- the $\sin, \cos$ are simply *defined* by the $x,y$ coordinates of points on the circle.  (Which IMS(ubjective)O is the best definition.)

Comment: @fleablood My previous comment pertains here.  I am nowhere near knowledgeable enough on the subject to even consider disagreeing with you.  Since I understand Apostol's approach, that is what I excerpted.  I am forced to consider any alternative approach (i.e. definition) radioactive, because I would be out of my depth discussing it.  This does not in any way suggest that Apostol's approach is the best way of treating the subject; how would I know what is best?

Comment: But what is the real definition of sine and cosine? How were they originally defined and computed?

Comment: @CuriousMind [Trigonometry:Plane Geometry] pre-dates Calculus by upwards of 2000 years.

Comment: @user2661923 how is it that triangles are related with the solution of the armonic oscilator, it does not make sense to me.

Comment: @CuriousMind I don't know anything about the armonic oscilator.